# How to reduce the space between lines of a datatable (package DT)

Tags: r, datatables, row, size, dt

I use RMarkdown to generate HTML reports. I have a table with 32 rows. I need to reduce the size between the rows to be able to see it without scrolling. I tried several options like width, height in datatable or in options but nothing worked.

With the iris dataset as example:

library(DT)
DT::datatable(iris,
colnames = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species'),
rownames=FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 32, dom='t'))

When I knit to HTML, the table takes a lot of place. So I would like to reduce the space between lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly reduce this space with the option`class = "compact"` in the `datatable` function.

Or you can have a better control as follows:

```r
library(DT)

js <- "
function(settings) {
  var table = this.api();
  table.rows().nodes().to$().css('height', '20px');
}
"

datatable(
  iris,
  options = list(
    "drawCallback" = JS(js)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried it but it is not enough, I hoped that we can choose the space we want.